# Why does the 3D graph of the function below appear serrated?

Tags: plotting

Why does the 3D graph of the function below appear serrated? Does it stand for discontinuities? What do serrated parts stand for in Mathematica?

As far as I can see, there is no discontinuity point when x, t is a real number.

```
   f = E^(I (2 - (245 t)/4 - x)) Sqrt[
   15/4 - (4 Sqrt[6] E^(2 (10 t + x)))/(1 + 16 E^(4 (10 t + x)))]

Plot3D[Abs[f]^2, {x, -20,20}, {t, 0,1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Second Example:

I don't understand what is the reason. What they stand for in Mathematica.

```
f = E^(I (2 + t - x))  Sqrt[
  15/4 + (256 Sqrt[6])/(16 E^(-32 (5 t + x)) + 16 E^(32 (5 t + x)))]
Plot3D[Abs[f]^2, {x, -20,20}, {t, 0,1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: The function is under-sampled in the plot. Increase the sampling by either increasing the `PlotPoints` and/or `MaxRecursion` For example, `Plot3D[Abs[f]^2, {x, -20, 20}, {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, MaxRecursion -> 7]`

Comment: It doesn't have a meaning; it's just a drawing error due to insufficient sampling of the function.

Answer (score 3):

> The function is under-sampled in the plot. Increase the sampling by either increasing the PlotPoints and/or MaxRecursion For example, Plot3D[Abs[f]^2, {x, -20, 20}, {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, MaxRecursion -> 7] –
> Bob Hanlon
> Apr 19 at 15:41

> It doesn't have a meaning; it's just a drawing error due to insufficient sampling of the function. –
> Sjoerd Smit Apr 19 at 15:42

To add to the above explanations, the plotter constructs a mesh by triangulating a rectangular grid. It then connects the points with triangles to create the surface.  With a coarse grid you get spikes when the surface curvature is too great.

Here's an illustration of refining the grid in the neighborhood(s) of large curvature.  This is controlled by `MaxRecursion` as Bob Hanlon points out.  The default value is `2` (shown in the center column). The magnitude of the spikiness diminishes as `MaxRecursion` increases. With a large value such as Bob suggests, the spikes become imperceptible.

```
GraphicsGrid[
 {#, Show[#, ViewPoint -> {1.25, 1, 4}] & /@ #} &@Table[
   Plot3D[Abs[f]^2, {x, -20, 20}, {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
    Mesh -> All, MaxRecursion -> mr, ViewPoint -> {5, 4, 0.5}, 
    PlotLabel -> MaxRecursion -> mr],
   {mr, 0, 4, 2}],
 ImageSize -> Full
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, the area is to big for the exponentials at the minimum. Your function has the form

```
f: x|-> = E^(I (2-(245 t)/4-x)) *
    Sqrt[15/4-(4 Sqrt[6] E^(2 (10 t+x)))/(1+16 E^(4 (10 t+x)))]
```

The factor in front is a unit phase factor, so the abs^2 is simply
at

```
15/4 -(4 Sqrt[6] E^(2 (10 t+x)))/(1+16 E^(4 (10 t+x))
```

Since the function is a function of 10t + x, its constant along 10t+x==const

It suffices to plot it as a function of Exp[ u = 2x] for t=0

```
Plot[15/4 - (4 Sqrt[6] E^x)/(1 + 16 E^(2 x)), {x, -6, 4}]
```

[image: 1d-plot over the pit]